# Mint 17 will not connect to internet after upgrade

Tags: networking, linux-mint, internet-connection

After installing the latest upgrades to Mint 17 MATE my Huawei E1552 mobile modem is not recognised by the system and I cannot connect to the internet.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you used before. Also as mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/221453/74792) you could try connecting it to an USB 2.0 port instead of a 3.0 one.

Comment: You may want to downgrade the packages that you suspect are involved in the issue, e.g. the `iw*firmware` packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue after upgrading from Linux Mint 16 to 17. Till Mint 16, internet was working fine. It stopped working after upgrading to 17.

Here's the solution I have:

`gksudo pluma /etc/resolv.conf`

`nameserver <IP address of router>`
`nameserver 192.168.1.1`

Save and close, Restart mint. Internet should start working now.

In my case I have a TP Link Modem / router device.

Comment: remember that nameserver 'IP' = default gateway as the router is either configured to obtain DNS from ISP or has manual DNS entries